# Django obj_create runs before my form validation

Tags: python, django, tastypie

In TastyPie obj_create runs before my form validation and it seems to be skipped, why?

**My code**

```
class AccountCreateResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = CompanyUser.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'accounts/create'
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=UserCreationForm)

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):

        CompanyUser.objects.create_user(email=bundle.data['email'],
                                            company=bundle.data['company'],
                                            password=bundle.data['company'])
```

Comment: Please add code of view, where this form used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing the `obj_create` overriding **wrong**. `obj_create` should also handle data validation. If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L2074), you'll see that a `self.save(bundle)` method is called. That method, amongst other things, calls the `is_valid` method which runs the validator. In your case, the `obj_create` method could look like this:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    bundle.obj = CompanyUser()
    bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle)
    bundle.obj.password = bundle.data['company']
    return self.save(bundle)
```

Note that since your resource is `ModelResource`, `full_hydrate` will set up necessary attributes on the `bundle.obj` for you. The important thing is to call `self.save(bundle)` and **return** the result of it.

If you *really* want to use `CompanyUser.objects.create_user()` try this one instead:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    bundle.obj = CompanyUser.objects.create_user(email=bundle.data['email'],
                                                 company=bundle.data['company'],
                                                 password=bundle.data['company'])
    self.is_valid(bundle)
    if bundle.errors:
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=self.error_response(bundle.request, bundle.errors))
    return bundle
```

Comment: thanks @kroolik that makes sense, but that won't call me CompanyUser.objects.create_user method will it?

Comment: No, it won't. If you _really_ want to use `CompanyUser.objects.create_user` assign the returned user to `bundle.obj` attribute and call `self.is_valid(bundle)` and check for `bundle.errors`. If any errors appeared, raise `ImmediateHttpResponse` like [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.10.0/tastypie/resources.py#L2217). Remember to return the `bundle` after you are done. Note that validation _after_ the object has been saved to the DB doesn't make a lot of sense.